# How to cascade optional parameter?

Tags: c#, refactoring, optional-parameters

I have a worker method with an optional parameter

```
Work(string input = DefaultInput)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

And I have a wrapper around this, which also take the string `input`, but this can also be optional...

```
WorkWrapper(int someParameter, string input = DefaultInput)
{
    //do initialization
    Work(input);

}
```

The problem here is I duplicate reference to DefaultInput, if, say, I change the default input of work to `NewDefaultInput`, I will need to update the workWrapper as well, otherwise it will still use the old default.

Is there a way so that the default input do not need to be declared twice? Possibly without having two overloads for workwrapper..

Comment: Are `Work` and `WorkWrapper` both `public`?  It seems like a bit of a strange idiom if so.  And if they weren't, you'd presumably only have to give defaults to the public-facing one.

Comment: @KirkWoll yes, the client code can either perform their own initialization or just use the one from the WorkWrapper... Hmm the method names are fake, maybe this is why you think it's strange?

Comment: How is `someParameter` used? It seems strange if it's not passed down to `Work` in some way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the defaults to be in sync between the two methods, you really don't need the default in the wrapper, right?

```
public void Work(string input = DefaultInput)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

…

```
public void WorkWrapper(int someParameter, string inputOverride = null)
{
    //do initialization

    if (inputOverride == null) Work();
    else Work(inputOverride);    
}
```

---

If they are in the same class/hierarchy, you could also just declare a `const` to ensure that the defaults remain the same.

```
private const string DEFAULT_INPUT = "Default Input"; // protected if in base class

public void Work(string input = DEFAULT_INPUT)
{
    //do stuff
}

public void WorkWrapper(int someParameter, string input = DEFAULT_INPUT)
{
    //do initialization
    Work(input);    
}
```